# connecting a database to a map

Tags: web-mapping, spatial-database, basemap

I have data about some monuments (date of construction, and other historical information), and I would like to build a sort of visual database to be put online, in which a series of markers should show up on a base map, each corresponding to a given monument. When users click on a given marker, a window should pup up providing info about the monument. 
While I am familiar with databasing, I have no experience with the described type of database. Is there a way to accomplish what I am after?

Comment: If you are using the ArcGIS platform I think creating attachments in a geodatabase and adding the feature class with them to an ArcGIS Online web map may be an approach worth investigating. Once you have tried something you will be in a better position to ask a focussed question.

Comment: thanks. I am going to read the earlier similar question. I will come back here if I have  further unaddressed questions.

Comment: @NewAtGis what location information do you have about each of the markers? Maybe LAT/LON coordinates or an address?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I have LAT/LON information for each point (=monument), plus some textual data for each one (=summary of monument's history).

Comment: @NewAtGis easiest way to see your data on a web map is to go over to Carto.com, get a free account, upload your data (spreadsheet? csv?) and it will read the LAT/LON and allow you to configure pop-ups / infowindows for the data you want to see, and adjust the symbols for the markers... give that a try to get a sense of what is possible... let me know what you come up with!